# Modify/clean field values before applying a query filter in MongoDB like in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a SQL Server query that I need to convert into a Mongo Query. As we all know that we can clean up fields in SQL before applying conditions to them e.g
In the 3rd line we are applying ltrim,rtrim on the clinics field before applying the like condition to it. Same with the reverse field in the query multiple times. If this was a single step query I would have done something maybe using aggregation but this is a multistep cleanup using replace, convert, ltrim, rtrim etc in different places.

Can someone please throw some light on how I could convert it. If someone is an expert in this domain and can convert it into Mongo, that would be great as well. Thanks :)

```
select rule from rules where 
isnull(status,0) = '1' AND isnull(deleted,0) = '0' 
AND (((ltrim(rtrim(isnull(clinics,'0'))) like '0%') OR 
( ',' + replace(replace(isnull(clinics,'0'),' ','') ,' ','') + ',' 
like '%,' + convert(varchar,"""+category+""") + ',%')) AND 
(',' + replace(replace(isnull(clinics,'0'),' ','') ,' ','') + ',' 
not like '%,-' + replace(convert(varchar,"""+category+"""),' ','') + ',%')) AND 
((( (ltrim(rtrim(isnull(reverse,'0'))) like '0%') OR  
(( ','+ replace(replace(isnull(reverse,'0'),' ','') ,' ','') + ',' 
like '%,' + convert(varchar,"""+primary+""") + ',%'))) 
AND (',' + replace(replace(isnull(reverse,'0'),' ','') ,' ','') + ',' 
not like '%,-' + replace(convert(varchar,"""+primary+"""),' ','') + ',%') ))
```

Comment: What has your research shown you? Where did you get stuck? And please don't tag SQL Server... you're not looking for help in that domain.

Comment: @DaleK I think a single step field cleaup and then filter can be made possible with a project and then match stage in an aggregation pipeline. However cleaning up multiple fields and then applying filters to them which are themselves coupled in using $ands and $or operators sounds impossible to me. I have no idea like how to go through this